What should be done with the [generative] tag?
I don't really like the generative tag, and I feel it's overly broad and there are more specific tags that should be used instead. At the same time, it fails the burnination criteria:

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
This tag can refer to genAI, other (non-ML) generative algorithms, and generating permutations/combinations of an array. This tag can refer to other topics as well.

Is it on-topic?
I guess it is, but there are more specific tags that would be more useful.

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
It means something "generative", but lacks specificity.

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
Not really, no.


As this tag has over 50 questions, unilaterally removing it is prohibited.

So, what should we do with this tag?

"Is it on-topic?" It's just an adjective, not a technical term as such. It isn't any more on-topic than "blue" or "hungry".

Proposal: disambiguate

Go over the questions and re-tag where appropriate. This should highlight what the common usages are.
See if there needs to be a new tag added for the rest. Or maybe just generative needs to be removed.

This would likely deal with the tag. It does sound overly broad and not really useful. So, finding the correct tags to replace it with should deal with the (at the time of writing) 57 questions that use it.

Planning section
List of all questions with the tags with proposed actions (feel free to edit suggestions):



Question
Current tags
Proposed action or tags




Uploading file with streaming - openai API
file-upload artificial-intelligence streaming openai-api generative
file-upload streaming openai-api python -- Also edit the question


How to SpanQuery the evaluations in arize phoenix
openai-api evaluation apache-phoenix generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Is it possible to disable AI input suggestions on my website
input artificial-intelligence generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Integrating GPT-4 with Team Foundation Server for Data Insights
artificial-intelligence openai-api gpt-3 gpt-4 generative
TO BE PROPOSED


How to Build a heatmap/efficency map prediction model?
conv-neural-network prediction building generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Can not solve this error in pytorch: RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation
python deep-learning pytorch generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Question about transition matrix Q in D3PM diffusion model for discrete state space
deep-learning probability stable-diffusion discrete generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Deploy LLM using Sagemaker and Langchain
streaming amazon-sagemaker endpoint large-language-model generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Suggested methods of timing individual prompt / completion response from LLM? any options other than 'time'?
artificial-intelligence inference large-language-model generative
TO BE PROPOSED


include gpt model to comment my code or data
artificial-intelligence openai-api generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Unable to reconstruct back the images using DDPM model
python huggingface generative diffusers
TO BE PROPOSED


GCP generativelanguage.googleapis.com not able to enable
google-cloud-platform google-cloud-vertex-ai generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Generate magazine flatplan with constraints
python constraints combinations permutation generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Checkpoints and model training
wandb generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Improving classification model (f1_score): real images vs generative images (fake)
generative-adversarial-network image-classification imbalanced-data generative
TO BE PROPOSED


What are the recommended security practices for training a chatbot with sensitive corporate data?
artificial-intelligence chatbot generative alpaca
TO BE PROPOSED


Writing phenaki video to file: Expected numpy array with ndim 3 but got 4
python pytorch torchvision generative pyav
python pytorch torchvision pyav


Weird behavor of generated object with arrays [duplicate]
javascript arrays object generative
javascript arrays object (remove the tag)


Place a random amount of numbers inside a grid that have a duplicate value
javascript algorithm random generative
javascript algorithm random (might lack enough details to answer)


J5 - JavaScript can't find variable "strokeCap"
javascript variables stroke generative
Close as typo - the code throws an error because the call is outside the function, not inside


Getting a combination of a list where it selects the current number in the list and below
python math combinations permutation generative
TO BE PROPOSED


having difficulty running p5js generative line art code
javascript p5.js generative
Close for lack of details (if it did have details, the generative-art might apply)


How to do recursion in a L-system inspired rewrite System, without DCG
prolog l-systems generative
prolog l-systems recursion


LineTrace algorithim in processing
processing generative
processing generative-art


tf.gradients() returns a list of [None]
python tensorflow keras generative-adversarial-network generative
python tensorflow keras generative-adversarial-network


How can I populate a list with points on a curved line?
python matplotlib pyautogui generative
python matplotlib pyautogui


Python: Generative Model LinAlgError: singular matrix error
python classification gaussian generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Gen: How to combine multiple generative function traces in a higher-order generative function?
julia inference generative probabilistic-programming generative-programming
julia inference probabilistic-programming generative-programming


Resolve exploding gradient in VAE
lstm gradient autoencoder generative-adversarial-network generative
lstm gradient autoencoder generative-adversarial-network machine-learning


How to send a picture to printer with python on macOS
python python-3.x macos python-imaging-library generative
python python-3.x macos python-imaging-library


Color Picker not Visible
java intellij-idea generative
java


Loss functions in GANs
python tensorflow machine-learning neural-network generative
python tensorflow machine-learning neural-network generative-adversarial-network


How can I extract the embeddings from an InfoGAN discriminator for a similarity search?
python tensorflow neural-network keras generative
TO BE PROPOSED


How to update GAN Generator and Discriminator asynchronously in Tensorflow?
tensorflow generative adversarial-machines
tensorflow adversarial-machines generative-adversarial-network


Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) in Keras - creating the combined model
keras generative adversarial-machines
keras adversarial-machines generative-adversarial-network


(MNIST - GAN) Discriminator and Generator error dropping close to zero after first iteration
python machine-learning tensorflow mnist generative
python machine-learning tensorflow mnist generative-adversarial-network


how the generator is trained with the output of discriminator in Generative adversarial Networks
machine-learning neural-network deep-learning generative
machine-learning neural-network deep-learning generative-adversarial-network


Does Keras nested models share attributes?
python keras generative
python keras generative-adversarial-network


Generative sequences in Tensorflow
python tensorflow recurrent-neural-network generative
TO BE PROPOSED


Generate text with a trained character level LSTM model
machine-learning tensorflow lstm generative
machine-learning tensorflow lstm


Use Generative or Discriminative model for classification?
machine-learning dataset classification generative
machine-learning dataset classification


Generating Images From Dataset Of Images Using A Neural Network
neural-network lstm generative generative-art
neural-network lstm generative-art


GAN Converges in Just a Few Epochs
machine-learning computer-vision keras generative
TO BE PROPOSED


DrRacket Generative Recursion Problems Help Needed
recursion racket generative
recursion racket


Having trouble rotating each individual element in a double for loop with Processing
java 2d processing generative
java 2d processing


Generating documents from LDA topic model
modeling lda documents mallet generative
modeling lda documents mallet classification


New to Processing need advice on Generative Stroke orbit from data
processing ellipse orbit generative
processing ellipse orbit generative-art


how handle categorical data in sklearn GMM mixture model
python scikit-learn generative
python scikit-learn machine-learning


Generative Recursion vs. Corecursion
recursion generative corecursion
recursion corecursion


Processing blendMode issue
processing graphical-logo generative-art generative
processing graphical-logo generative-art


Difference between Generative, Discriminating and Parametric, Nonparametric Algorithm/Model
machine-learning modeling generative
machine-learning classification?


What's the relationshiop between Xtext and ANTLR?
parsing antlr xtext generative
parsing antlr xtext


generative typography?
apache-flex actionscript-3 fonts typography generative
apache-flex actionscript-3 fonts typography


Creating a repeatable, random looking distribution of objects in Flash
flash actionscript-3 actionscript random generative
TO BE PROPOSED


How would I go about plotting "live" stock market data with Processing, jQuery, Pure Data or Max/MSP?
jquery processing finance data-mining generative
Close the question as too broad


What is the difference between a generative and a discriminative algorithm? [closed]
algorithm machine-learning generative
algorithm machine-learning classification


Procedural music generation techniques [closed]
procedural generative
procedural-music



Notes:

Some usage seems to be around machine learning and generative models. An SME might need to weigh in if there is a call for a new tag for this.
Few usages relate to recursion. Specifically generative recursion (in short, the recursion step there generates new data and recurses through it). Perhaps using recursion in that case is enough but maybe a new tag can be considered.


For me, all post about generate IA should not be specially tagged as they will also be tagged by the IA they're using or the platform ([tag:openia-api], machine-learning etc)

We should just burninate the tag. "generative" by itself is not useful, descriptive, monolithic, or on-topic. Perhaps a "generative-AI" tag is useful, but then we should probably re-tag all of the [tag:Artificial-intelligence] questions from before ChatGPT came out as [tag:traditional-ai]. Now that cleanup has begun, there are certainly less than 50 questions with the tag remaining.

@TylerH So far, I've not even seen anything that uses [generative] for "generative AI". There are some "AI-related" (mostly ML) usages but I've yet to see a question that asks about genAI topic. And it's likely it would need some other tag for it, too.
